# Is there any method to call back when internet is connected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

i checked answers in here about internet connections and reachability classes but i could not find answer to my question yet. I need to know if any delegate method exist to call back when app is connected to internet. I don't want to check if internet exist with NSTimer or NSThread any moment. I would be happy to know any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a notification `kReachabilityChangedNotification` in `Reachability` class, which is post when reachability of internet changed. Also, there are `reachableBlock` and `unreachableBlock`, look at

`-(void)reachabilityChanged:(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags)flags`

in `Reachability.m` file

Comment: that is some thing awesome to know..:)